# GetFeatureInfo problem with .ftl and .sld

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo, grib

I'm configuring a WMS that exposes measurements read from GRIB files. I initially configured the layer that uses the default style (Raster.sld), then I configured two .ftl files to change the display of the GetFeatureInfo:

- header.ftl:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Geoserver GetFeatureInfo output</title>
   </head>
   <style type="text/css">
         table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
                 border:1px solid #ddd;
                 border-collapse:collapse;
                 margin:0;
                 padding:0;
                 font-size: 90%;
                 padding:.2em .1em;
color:blue;
         }
         table.featureInfo th{
             padding:.2em .2em;
                 text-transform:uppercase;
                 font-weight:bold;
                 background:#eee;
         }
         table.featureInfo td{
                 background:#fff;
         }
         table.featureInfo tr.odd td{
                 background:#eee;
         }
         table.featureInfo caption{
                 text-align:left;
                 font-size:100%;
                 font-weight:bold;
                 text-transform:uppercase;
                 padding:.2em .2em;
         }
   </style>
   <body>
```

which only puts the basic blue color and everything works.

So once this was done I created a style (.sld) that maps the two wind components `u` and `v` calculating magnitude (speed) and direction:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld ./StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>windbarbs</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>windbarbs</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:RasterAsPointCollection">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <!-- Activate the logic to recognize the emisphere -->
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>emisphere</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>True</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>interpolation</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>InterpolationBilinear</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>100000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>500000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>5000000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>0.2</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>10000000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>20000000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>60000000</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>0.02</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>windbarbs://default(
                  <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                    <ogc:Add>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                    </ogc:Add>
                  </ogc:Function>)[m/s]?emisphere=
                  <ogc:PropertyName>emisphere</ogc:PropertyName>
                </WellKnownName>
                <Stroke>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke">000000</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                  <!-- Value to transform -->
                  <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                    <ogc:Add>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                    </ogc:Add>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>1.543333332</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>32</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
              </Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                  <!-- Value to transform -->
                  <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                    <ogc:Add>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                    </ogc:Add>
                  </ogc:Function>

                  <!-- Output values and thresholds -->
                  <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>1.543333332</ogc:Literal>

                  <ogc:Function name="toDegrees">
                    <ogc:Add>
                      <ogc:Function name="atan2">                      
                        <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                      </ogc:Function>
                      <ogc:Literal>3.1415</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Add>
                  </ogc:Function>
                </ogc:Function>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">
                    <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>
                  </CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>3</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

My problem is that with this style I manage the graphic part of the layer correctly without errors, but it no longer applies the .ftl file that worked before.

It seems like changing .sld makes it point to another directory. Can someone help me?

Comment: Because you are using a transformation function there is no file to apply the flt to so I guess it won't work. I've no idea how much effort it would be to modify the code base to make it work